# When exactly can "to be" be omitted in the sentence? (want ~ to be p.p)

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context

> UEFA said it **wants** the rules of soccer **changed** to protect players from concussions, after its own policy for dealing with head injuries came in for critism.

I think in this sentence, "to be" was omitted before "changed", so originally it has to be "it **wants the rules of soccer to be changed"**(,right?)

But I'm not sure when exactly I can omit "to be" in the sentence.
For example, if the structure is Subject + "want" + Object + Object Complement, then can I always omit "to be"? As in,

> I want it to be understood more.
>
> I want it understood more.

Is this rule applied to other verbs as well?

Comment: What is O.C? Please keep in mind that not everyone is familiar which the abbreviations you use.

Comment: @user178049 sorry I edited!

Comment: Idiomatic *He wants his head examined* can be understood to mean *He's crazy, he **should** be assessed by a psychiatrist* (even though he himself probably has no such wish). Which *isn't* the same thing as *He wants his **to be** head examined* (not a very likely utterance, but that would almost certainly be understood to mean he really ***does*** have such a wish). Note that for some speakers *He wants his head **examining*** is also syntactically acceptable - it would normally be understood as carrying the first meaning here, but there's no way to include ***to be*** in that one.

Comment: (Maybe *The [football] referee wants his eyes tested / testing* would be a better example.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only a small number of verbs that take a past-participial clause as a catenative complement, most of which allow an infinitival complement too. Some of the verbs are "want", "order", and "report" (CGEL, 1244—1245)*.

Here are some examples:

> i. UEFA said it wants the rules of soccer (to be) changed 
>   ii. He order it (to be) destroyed 
>   iii. They are feared (to have been)abducted

With "want", this construction is only possible when the main clause is active (cf. the unacceptable **the rules of soccer are wanted changed*).

It's to be distinguished from the concealed passive construction, in which case, "want" is synonymous to "need":

> His hair wants *<sup>?</sup>cut/cutting*

In this construction, the version with the gerund-participle "cutting" is more common. The version with the past-participle "cut" is restricted to certain regional dialects such as Scottish.

---

*Huddleston R. D., & Pullum G. K. (2002). *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press.